# Why concat empty character is faster than .toString()?

Tags: javascript, performance, algorithm, optimization

I have this code:

```
var boo = 123123;
```

I want to convert that number to string and **conact string** is faster than native JavaScript **.toString()**:

*Faster*:

```
var foo = boo + "";
```

*Slower*:

```
var foo = boo.toString();
```

jsPerf: http://jsperf.com/concat-string-vs-tostring

Why **.toString()** is slower than concating empty character? And finally I want to know is that a correct approach to use `+ ""` technique instead of `.toString()`?

Comment: I'd expect that the overhead of a function call that has to look up to the Number prototype is slower than the built-in string concatenation overloading of the plus operator.

Comment: And yes, it is perfectly valid, though you should consider readability more important than a microsecond in your script's execution time.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté AFAIK all of Java programmers use `boo + ""`! Do you think it's not human readable?

Comment: @Afshin, can you determine at first glance that's a conversion to string?

Comment: It is human readable for me, but those concepts vary from team to team. `=]` Then again, people say I write self-obfuscated code, so I try stay at the "most readable" side of what I write when making contributions to larger projects.

Comment: The benchmark results are probably distorted due to certain runtime optimization techniques that can be used as the repetitive operation always yields the same result. You may want to try [this benchmark](http://jsperf.com/concat-string-vs-tostring/7) instead.

Comment: it's non-human-readable to the extent that the first time someone looks at it, they aren't likely going to recognize it as a string conversion depending on the context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Results will vary depends on javascript engine used. On chrome one I'm getting the same results as Afshin.

So why actually one is slower than another? It's because on `toString` there will be one more call to C functions inside V8. You can try next to see that by yourself:

- Open empty tab in chrome(to avoid any side effects from already opened pages)
- Open Developers Tools
- Open Profiles tab and start new profile
- Go to Console tab and insert `script1` script, press enter.
- Go to Profile again and stop profiling
- Repeat the same with `script2`
- script 1: `var boo = 123123; var foo = boo + "";`
- script 2: `var boo = 123123; var foo = boo.toString();`

In my case first will result in next stacktrace:

```
  InjectedScript.evaluate
    InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap
```

while second one:

```
  InjectedScript.evaluate
    InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap
      InjectedScript._evaluateOn
        evaluate
```

I think it's more has to do with engine internals than official js spec and probably could be optimized to use the same code path.